# Maintain a sorted ObservableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout-2.0

I'd like to have an `ko.observableArray` that maintains its own sort order, where the sort order is dependent on a computed property of each item.

I'd like this to work:

```
var threads = ko.observableArray().extend({ sorted: Thread.desc });
```

I have an attempt [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E49Y3/8/) that uses an extender, but changes to the child observable do not cause a re-sort.

Is this how ko is supposed to work, or am I missing a step?

EDIT: Turns out I had the dependencies wrong. Changing `messages` does not mark `threads` as changed, even though `preview` is called within the sort method, so of course it doesn't sort.

Still working out a concise solution to maintaining a sorted list by being dependent on a child.

Comment: jsfiddle shows `msg5,msg2,msg1`. is not what you expect?

Comment: it shows it only after "manually" calling sort in the setTimeout. I'd expect it to happen when a new message is added.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up going with http://jsfiddle.net/E49Y3/11/, where I just keep a separate computed property:

```
model.threads = ko.observableArray();
model.threadsDesc = ko.computed(function(){
    return model.threads().sort(Thread.desc)
});
```

Works!